# DDD(ドメイン駆動設計)で集約にまたがるテーブル

Tags: データベース設計, ドメイン駆動設計

DDDにおいてテーブルが複数の集約にまたがることはアンチパターンと言えますか？

テーブルが集約にまたがることを認めた場合懸念されることとして以下が浮かびます。他にもある場合教えていただきたいです。
・集約と対応するテーブルのうちいくつかを変更する際、他の集約への影響を考える必要がある。

一方でドメインサービスと集約でテーブルを共有することは見かけることが多いように思います。
ドメインサービスと集約でテーブルがまたがるのが許されるのは、この２つでは関心ごとが共通している場合が多いので修正漏れが起こりにくいのでよしとするという理解をしていますがこれも間違っていたらご指摘いただきたいです。

具体的に私が直面しているのはテーブルがサブクラスとスーパークラスのような構成になっていて各サブクラステーブルとその周辺のテーブルが各集約にあたり、スーパークラステーブルのidを持つ共通テーブルを各集約に含んでしまうか別集約にするか迷っております。